# How to print the Longest Palindromic Subsequence? If there are multiple LPS we need to print the one which starts at lowest index

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Here is my code, it prints the LPS correctly but can't print the one which starts from the lowest index if multiple LPS exist. I tried handling a case seperately when dp[i][j-1]==dp[i-1][j] but for some reason that dosen't work also. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
public class Solution { 
public static String longestPalinSubstring(String str) {
    String rev = reverse(str);
    int n = str.length();
    int[][] dp = new int[n+1][n+1];
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if(str.charAt(i-1)==rev.charAt(j-1)){
                dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i-1][j-1];
            }else{
                dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    int i=n, j=n;
    String ans="";
    while(i>0 && j>0){
        if(str.charAt(i-1)==rev.charAt(j-1)){
            ans+=str.charAt(i-1);
            --i;
            --j;
        }else{
            if(dp[i-1][j]<dp[i][j-1]){
                j--;
            }else{
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return reverse(ans);
}

public static String reverse(String s){
    String ans = "";
    for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        ans += s.charAt(i);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the longest palindromic subsequence (not its length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892912/how-to-find-the-longest-palindromic-subsequence-not-its-length)

Comment: Take the DP 2D matrix. Apply some backtracking on it to get all possible sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing an alternative yet easy dynamic programming implementation which will solve your problem.
`dp[i][j] = 1` represents palindrome of size `i` ending at position `j` in the given string.

Example: `str = "aprabaprrbcb"` then `dp[3][5] represents "aba"`. Since `"aba" is palindrome`, `dp[3][5] = 1`.

We just need to check if first and last character of the current sub-string is `equal`. If equal then check if `inner sub-string` (string after removing first and last character of current string) is palindrome or not. Since the inner sub-string size will be `i-2` and ends at `j-1`, hence we check `dp[i-2][j-1]`.

Now maintain 2 variables `lar_size` and `lar_pos` for size of longest palindrome and last index of that palindrome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LPS { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        int n= str.length();
        int[][] dp = new int[n+1][n+1];
        int lar_size=-1;
        int lar_pos= -1;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            dp[0][i]=1; //string of length 0 ending at position i is a palindrome
            dp[1][i]=1; //string of length 1 ending at position i is a palindrome
        }
        //
        for( int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            for( int j=i; j<=n;j++){
                if(str.charAt(j-1) == str.charAt(j-i)){
                    if(dp[i-2][j-1] == 1){
                        dp[i][j]=1;
                        if(lar_size < i){ // for lowest index palindrome
                            lar_size=i;
                            lar_pos=j;
                        }
                        
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lar_size+" "+(lar_pos-lar_size+1));
        String ans="";
        for(int i=0;i<lar_size;i++){
            ans+=str.charAt(lar_pos-lar_size+1 +i);
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```